mysql procedure problem with encoding non english languages
I have a mysql procedure as following:
CREATE PROCEDURE `add_package` ( 
    IN  package__name   VARCHAR(255),
    IN  package__parent BIGINT(20)
)

BEGIN

    DECLARE inserted_id     BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE grand__parent   BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;

    INSERT INTO prs_package_heads (package_name,package_parent) VALUES (package__name,package__parent);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO inserted_id;

    IF inserted_id > 0 THEN 
        SET @@GLOBAL.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
        SET @@session.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;

        CALL package_grand_parent(inserted_id ,grand__parent);
        UPDATE prs_package_heads SET grand_parent= grand__parent WHERE ID= inserted_id;
    END IF;

    SELECT inserted_id;

END

When I save a string with this procedure in english language there is no problem with characters, But when I save string in persion language it is saving in database like ??????????? characters!
Note: previously I was using KSWEB server and there was no problem. But now I use XAMPP server and this problem is cause!
I think that there is no bug in my code and the problem is from my local server. How I can fix it?

please edit your question to show (as text, not image) output of show create table prs_package_heads;  you will also likely need to show the code that is doing the saving in database
